# spring boot enableoauth2sso

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a successful client integration with a OIDC provider using @EnableOath2Sso annotation. However, for logout I struggle a bit. The provider requires the idToken as a parameter to the logout request. My setup is:

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration
public class OpenIDConnectConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**").
            authorizeRequests().
            anyRequest().authenticated().and().
            logout().logoutSuccessHandler(this::onLogout).and().
            csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
}


public void onLogout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
}
```

How can I access the idToken from the onLogout method so that I can redirect to the correct URL to the OIDC provider?

Comment: Check the `Authentication` object, it _might be on there depending on how you handle the setup of the Authentication object. If not you could expand the Principal to store it.

Comment: Since I'm using @EnableOauth2Sso, the authentication object is handled by spring. Unfortunately, it does not contain the id token. I have not found out how I can override the code that sets up the autentication object.